# Possible to draw an Item in a Grid with only 3 sides of a Frame?

Tags: grid-layouts

I'm trying to draw a `Grid` of characters where some of the characters have `Frame` lines on 3 sides.  For example:

```
  +   +
x | x | x
  +---+ 
x   x   x

x   x   x
```

That's something like a `Grid[item = Table[x,{3},{3}]]`, except with `item[[1,2]] = Item[x,FrameStyle->{{White,Black},{Black,Black}}]`, except that produces a complete box around the `x` for me.

When the documentation says:

> `FrameStyle->{{left,right},{bottom,top}}` specifies that different sides of a graphics frame should be drawn with different styles.

I fear that the "...of a graphics frame..." part means that this will work for a `Plot`, but not for a `Grid`.

Is there a way to style a frame such that I only draw three edges of it? It doesn't have to be pretty--I'm planning on generating the `Grid` from some data that I have lying around.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about this?

```
Grid[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, Item[5, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}], 6}}]
```

[image: frame]

Comment: You beat me. :-)

Comment: A very rare occurrence.