# How to control divider length in a grid

Tags: grid-layouts

I want to display a table like this:

[image]

And use `Divider` I can only get this so far

```
t=Table[x, {10}, {10}];    
Grid[t, 
     Dividers -> {{{{True, False}}, {-1 -> False, 
         1 -> False}}, {{{True, False}}, {-1 -> False, 1 -> False}}}]
```

[image]

How can I remove the extra part of the divider?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4383/121

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Slightly* less dirty:

```
d = 10;
t = Table[x, {d}, {d}];
Grid[MapAt[Item[#, Frame -> White] &, t, Tuples[{Range@d, {-2, -1}}]],
     Dividers -> {#, #} &@Thread[(# -> Black &)[Range[3, d, 2]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, however I recommend `Frame -> None` as this will work even if the background is not white, and it avoids altering the spacing which `Frame` otherwise does.

Comment: @belisarius I'm confused about the negative numbers in  `Tuples[{Range@d, {-2, -1}}]`, and wondering how does it affect `MapAt`? I read the documentation of `MapAt` and did not see the case for negative numbers appear.

Answer (score 3):

This is something of a hack because I had to adjust the `Dashing` parameters by eye, but maybe it will give you an idea you can chew on.

```
t = Table[x, {10}, {10}];
Grid[t, 
  Dividers -> 
    {{{{True, False}}, {-1 -> False, -3 -> False, 1 -> False}}, 
    {{{Dashing[{170., 100.}], False}}, {-1 -> False, 1 -> False}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Really dirty :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the option `Frame`

```
Grid[t, Dividers -> {#, #} & @ Thread[Range[3, 10, 2] -> True],
 Frame -> {None, None, Thread[Tuples[{Range @ 10, {-1, -2}}] -> Opacity[0]]}, 
 FrameStyle -> {Red, Thick}]
```

[image]